# Can I use a VPN on home network to make Playstion Vue work in 2 places?

Tags: networking, vpn, video-streaming, playstation

I'm trying out Playstation Vue, a streaming tv service.  Problem is I want to use it at the same time while at home and away.  Playstation Vue detects when I'm not on the home network and won't allow me to view content when I'm away.  Will setting up a VPN at home and connecting to it solve the location problem?

Thanks,
Dave :)

Comment: It may solve the location problem, but if, like most people, you have an asymmetric Internet connection the data stream will use your up-load data rate, typically a tenth of the down-load speed, which may well be insufficient for streaming. But it is very easy to set up, so why not try it?

Comment: Unless you have a minimum 30mbit/s _upload_ from your home's ISP, it's not going to be worth it, as HD will likely not be possible.  If you do have around that or higher, then yes a VPN would be sufficient.  It would be best to configure it on your router, although you can run an OpenVPN server from any non-Windows PC. Here's a [pre-built server config](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN/OpenVPN-Server.conf), along with a [pre-built client config](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN/Client.ovpn)

Comment: OpenVPN is available on Windows as a server - - https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide

Comment: @JW0914 I have a + 15MB/sec upload speed.  I'm surprised I'd need more as a slingbox uses less than 3megabits/sec for HD.  I figure at 15MB/sec I could run 5X that.

Comment: @DavidAubin SlingBox is not the same as PS Vue (different coding, different compression algorithms/ratios, etc.)... you'll need to determine what the download speed requirements of PS Vue is... your upload speed must meet or exceed that value if using a VPN for external access (one reddit thread said 10mbit/s preferred per stream).  15mbit/s seems fine for one stream, however you will need to ensure you configure your client to only use the VPN for PS Vue traffic and nothing else, else you will likely see quality degradation.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I wasn't aware of that =]  In that case, I would strongly caution against setting up an OpenVPN server on a Windows PC since it would mean passing WAN traffic directly to that PC, bypassing the router and it's firewall.  A WAN VPN should be configured on the WAN facing router, not downstream.  If a WAN VPN is going to be configured, it's best to do so on a router running opensource firmware (I recommend LEDE), otherwise the user has little control over security of the VPN or tuning.  Ubiquiti's EdgeRouter X can be picked up on Newegg for ~$55 (they're supported by LEDE).

Comment: @JW0914 Glad to enlighten =) But yes, a non-windows platform would be preferable, I'm sure.

Comment: I'm considering an ASUS AC1900 as my VPN server :)

Comment: I set up the wifi router to use Open VPN.  It works perfectly on my Android phone.  I'm pleased with the results.  Not sure how to close the question, but yes, the VPN solution works with Playstation Vue!

Answer (score 0):

I set up the wifi router to use Open VPN. It works perfectly on my Android phone. I'm pleased with the results. Yes, the VPN solution works with Playstation Vue!